# How can I set non-persistent debugging parameters in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code to do some Python debugging. When debugging, I want to specify some temporary arguments to use. These are mostly just dummy values, since its for a test. I do not want the arguments checked into version control.

At the moment I'm modifying the `launch.json` file to add the args. However, this gets checked into version control. How can I specify arguments without adding to this file?

Normal Visual Studio IDE creates a temporary file for debug settings that doesn't get checked in. I was hoping for something similar to that for VSCode.